# Can't login newly created customer upgraded from 1.9.3 to 1.9.4.1

Tags: magento-1.9

I have checked all the modules. The issue found in /core/Mage/Log/Model/Visitor.php

There is an issue with Magento Log module with "custom_login" event. I have commented code of dispatch event from core/Mage/Log/etc/config.xml.

now my login is working fine.

but I am not able to know what is the issue with bindCustomerLogin function in /core/Mage/Log/Model/Visitor.php

Only newly created customers can't login with store2. Store1 customer able to login.